# How can I send grep results into a different output file for each input file?

Tags: grep

I have a folder that contains text files. I need to extract lines that has 'BA' from these text files . I used  grep command to print the lines with BA. I would like to save the outputs to another folder with the same file names. How can I change the following code?

```
grep "  BA  "  dir/*.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in dir/*.txt; do
   grep "  BA  " $i > $newdir/`basename $i`
done
```

Note the use of [basename](http://ss64.com/bash/basename.html), which takes `dir/a.txt` (say) and returns `a.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for GNU parallel:

```
parallel --dry-run grep '"  BA  "' '{} > otherdir/{/}' ::: dir/{a,b,c}.txt
```

Output:

```
grep "  BA  " dir/a.txt > otherdir/a.txt
grep "  BA  " dir/b.txt > otherdir/b.txt
grep "  BA  " dir/c.txt > otherdir/c.txt
```

Remove `--dry-run` when you're happy with what you see.

`{}` is replaced by the inputs after `:::` (these can also come from stdin or a file), `{/}` is the basename of `{}`.